# Programmatically instantiating a NSPopUPMenu without a NSPopUpButton with Cocoa OSX

Tags: cocoa, macos, popupmenu

A while back I made a cocoa widget that was a button that when pressed, would pop up a popup menu and handle the selection.  This was quite trivial using the NSPopupMenuButton class but now I need to do something slightly different.  I have an openGL widget and when I click on a certain part of this widget, I need to pop up the same pop up menu that you get from the NSPopupMenuButton but without the button.  I could not find any reference to this menu class itself inside the documentation for the NSPopupMenuButton.  Is what I am trying to do possible?  Or do I need to build this pop up menu from scratch?

Comment: Question doesn't parse. Try moving the commas around a bit for better readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no separate NSPopUpMenu. The menu of an NSPopUpButton is an NSMenu.

If you want a pop-up menu without a pop-up button, you'll need to use NSPopUpButtonCell to display the menu. Of course, this is assuming you have a good reason to fake a pop-up button in an OpenGL view, instead of simply using the standard NSPopUpButton.